# Check the real availability of IndexedDB in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I have to check the IndexedDB availability for the Firefox browser only. Currently I do the trick with this :

```
var IDB_SUPPORTED = 'indexedDB' in window;
```

Simple. But if I disable IndexedDB in `about:config` (with the `dom.indexedDB.enabled` parameter), `IDB_SUPPORTED` is still `true`.

How can I check the real availability of IndexedDB in Firefox without any third-party library like Modernizr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
try { window.indexedDB } catch (err) { IDB_SUPPORTED = false; }
```